# Tubular Neighborhood Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I am trying to prove the existence of Tubular Neighborhoods in Symplectic Geometry and to start off I need to show that :

> Let $X$ be a compact submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  let $U^{\epsilon}=\{p\in \mathbb{R}^n : |p-q|<\epsilon , $ for some $q\in X\}$.  Then for small enough $\epsilon$ each $p \in U^{\epsilon}$ has a unique nearest point $q\in X$.

Now proving the existence of this point I was able to do using the fact $X$ is compact and the continuity of the metric. But proving the statement that for small enough we have a unique nearest point I still haven't managed to  figure out and can't seem to use the condition that $X$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^k$.So will the fact that he is in deed a submanifold necessary? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The border of $X$? $X$ we take to be a compact submanifold *without* boundary.

Comment: One thing you might try is to take $F_\epsilon$ to be the set of points in $U_\epsilon$ which fail to have a unique closest point in X. So there is at least 2 closest points. By taking smaller and smaller epsilons, pick out a sequence of points which converges and show it must have two limits which is absurd since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to the case of codimension 1. The idea of the proof is the same for the general case. The proof is long and I have some reference for it but not in english. In the literature you usually find the abstract counterpart of this result which is too much for your question.

You have to consider the (sometimes called) Fermi parameterization of the "tubular neighborhood". What I mean is that if $X$ is your submanifold, you have to consider the map $(x,t)\in X\times \mathbb{R}\to x+t n(x)$ where $n$ is the unit normal field. Then you have to apply the inverse function theorem which holds as soon as $t$ is sufficiently small. The compactness of the manifold allows for the "uniform" choice of the $\epsilon$. Indeed, the result still holds when the submanifold is closed, but now $\epsilon$ is a positive function defined on $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by compactness gives orientabilitity?  And even if the normal space is orientable, why would the normal bundle have a section?  (I understand the argument if $X$ has codimension $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: You seem to have forgotten, as @JasonDeVito suggested, that $X$ may have codimension $>1$. You really need to map the normal bundle of $X$ to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: The idea of the proof does not change. Just parameterize the unit ball in the normal space (to replace the $t$ variable in codimension $1$ construction). And then use IFT. The proof is long. I don't think the OP  pretends a full proof here. Just the idea behind.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Jason De Vito, I mean that if a submanifold is compact than it is orientable and I am allowed to simplify the notation by using the normal vector field instead of the normal vector space.

Comment: @Kosh:  To be clear, I agree that a closed codim $1$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be orientable, but in general codimensions this is false (since $\mathbb{R}P^2$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^4$.)  Anyway, you get a +1 from me.

Comment: @JasonDeVito sometimes my tone appears wrong, so just to be clear, I appreciated that you pointed out these important remarks. Ciao.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen the other answer but I wanted to provide a self-contained proof for every codimension. I’ll omit a few details though.

By taking subsequences and charts, we can assume that $X=0.5B^d \times \{0\} \subset B^n$, and that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is given by $|\psi(x)-\psi(y)|^2$ for an open map $\psi: B^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ which is a diffeomorphism onto its image. We can furthermore assume that the problematic points (as well as their projections) accumulate at $0$.

Define $\delta: (x,y) \in B^n \times X \longmapsto |\psi(x)-\psi(y)|^2$, and $f(x,y)=(d_y\delta)(x,y) \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^*$.

If $y$ is a projection of $x$, then $f(x,y)=0$.

So to derive a contradiction, by the theorem of implicit functions it’s enough to show that $(d_yf)(0,0): \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^d)^*$ is invertible.

But it’s not too hard to see that $f(x,y)(h)=(\psi(y)-\psi(x))\cdot \psi’(y)(h)$, and thus $((d_yf)(0,0)(u))(h)=\psi’(0)u \cdot \psi’(0)h$, so it’s a nondegenerate bilinear form so is invertible and we are thus done.